# Putting into Diffrent Files With same name. GulpJS

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp

I have this forum im making im sure you guys know by now, but my problem is that i need to 'concurenctly' change css files to sass. Here is my example heierchy in the project:

```
app/
         components/
                                     404/
                                             controllers/
                                                         404Ctrl.js
                                             sass/
                                                       404.scss
                                             css/
                                                       404.min.css
                                    home/

                                             controllers/
                                                         homeCtrl.js
                                             sass/
                                                  home.scss
                                             css/
                                                  home.min.css
                                  etc... much more
```

So as you can see i have a sass folder and css folder.. well what i want to do is that, whenever i change my scss file, i want to minfy it and then put it in the css file.. But i have many components like 404,home,authDesc,etc... I need to somehow when i type gulp sass, i want it to do for many folders.. This is what i have so far, but the problem like i said before i need to know which destination to put it in..

This is what i have so far:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('app/components/{COMPONENT_NAME}/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/history/css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/components/{COMPONENT_NAME}/css'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

But i need to change that {COMONENT_NAME} with the desired component. Help would be greatly appreciated

### EDIT

I found a mini-technique to do it, but this has some errors:

```
var PATHS_SASS = {
    scss_org : [
        'app/components/404/sass/404.scss',
        'app/components/auth/sass/auth.scss'
    ],  
    css_dest : [
        'app/components/404/css',
        'app/components/auth/css'
    ]

}
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  for(var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        gulp.src(PATHS_SASS.scss_org[i])
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/history/css'))
        .pipe(minifyCss({
          keepSpecialComments: 0
        }))
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS_SASS.css_dest[i]))
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a main.scss file where you import all your other sass files and then only compile that file. You should find a perfect code example in this [repo](https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/sass-boilerplate)

Comment: what about if i dont want to put everything in one file? Is my original task before you changed it possible?

Comment: Then sorry, I don't know how to do it with gulp but have you considered webpack? It can fix all that for you without you having to worry about the sass and css

Comment: Mostafa, i found a mini-teechnique, but that has some errors. Maybe you can fix it? I edited my question adresseing this